# Exposing Qt C++ QObject to Python

Tags: python, c++, qt, boost, qscript

I have a software component (Qt/C++ GUI-less library) that performs some data-intensive manipulation.

What is the best way to expose it's functionality as a Python native extension? Wrapping it by hand in Boost::Python? Anything QObject/QMetaObject based instead? Perhaps reusing QScript wrappers?

*Note - I know this question borders on the soft-rec, but I presume there might be a canonical way to do it that I know nothing about, and I hope this question would not devolve into a personal preference comment storm*

Comment: Did you try to use PyQt? http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk/software/pyqt/intro

Comment: I assume it's just a way to use Qt's GUI libraries directly from python. Do they have something for packaging custom C++ code (heavily using Q_PROPERTIES and Qt-specific containers)?

Comment: I did not use it heavily but as I understand you can mix C++ and Python using PyQt.

Comment: PyQt uses something called SIP for wrappers - and even the simple qpoint.sip is absolutely hideous :(

Comment: They have a lot of samples. Anyway you can also try to play with swig? but it is not so reliable since Qt uses Moc.